# What's the difference between Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Cloud live image?

Tags: server, cloud

I'm not sure what the difference is or which one I should download. I have a server rack I'm putting together and I don't know much about servers. I love ubuntu though. If I want to use this a work server to host things and a personal server for experimenting, which should I use?

I also might dual boot this with windows server 2008 eventually. I'm using a dell power edge 2500 with 5 scuzzy drive totaling 100gbs and maybe 2gbs of ram.

Comment: Note that the "Cloud Live" thing has been discontinued, so people might be looking for a ["(Live) Server" installer vs "Server Cloud Images"](https://serverfault.com/questions/438611/what-are-ubuntu-cloud-images) comparison instead.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do with your server, but probably you want to use Ubuntu server.

Cloud live is an image that you can write in a USB drive and boot to create a cloud computing environment. Please note that this is a live system (i have never used it, so i don't know if you have the option to install it in your system). Also, if you really want to setup a cloud system you can install Ubuntu server and the cloud tools after.

So, unless you want to *try* a cloud computing system, you need Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud live is actually non-persistant (atleast what i used) , that means what you do on it is lost after you reboot.... but it is only a demonstration and use of OpenStack if you dont want to install it (without juju its difficult , rather too difficult (but i did it :) without juju only to find out about juju next day :)).

So if you want to see how private cloud is , try for cloud image , or if you want to use trial for EC2 its good , for checking it out. If you are not interested in cloud computing, please avoid it ...